# Mock testing scenarios when the method itself creates a class using a Factory method

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, moq, factory

See this example code below;

```
public Car {
  public void BuildCar(CarType carType) {
    var engineType = EngineTypeFactory.GetEngineType(carType);

    var engineInsertionResult = InsertEngine(engineType);

    if (!engineInsertionResult.IsRunning) {
      throw new OhNoEngineFailedException("Engine Failure");
    }
  }

  private EngineInsertionResult InsertEngine(EngineType engineType) {
    var ignitionResult = engineType.TurnOn();

    return new EngineInsertionResult() {
        IsRunning: ignitionResult.IsEngineRunning;
      }
  }
}

public static EngineTypeFactory {
  public EngineType GetEngineType(CarType carType) {
    switch (carType) {
        case carType.Petrol:
            return EngineType.Petrol:
        case carType.Electric:
            return EngineType.Electric;
    }
  }
}
```

What's the best practice around testing the result (using Mocking) from the `InsertEngine` method to cover a scenario where it could return `IsRunning` as either true or false given that we create the `EngineType` using the factory method within the `BuildCar` method?!

I understand I could create the `EngineType` outside of the `BuildCar` method and pass that into the method to achieve, which is nice and simple but there's always a situation where I need to build the concrete classes using a Factory method and my head gets into a mess about if this the *correct* way or not?!

I was just wondering if there was a pattern I'm obviously missing or this is just the trade off for a scenario you can't really test unless you interface off the `EngineTypeFactory` and inject that into the `Car` class so that you can handle the `GetEngineType` return result directly? which seems excessive for testing purposes maybe?!

Comment: Refactor to inject the factory class?

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if there was a pattern or something I was missing when/if I was to create a number of different classes using different Factory methods within the `BuildCar` so I then didn't have a case where I was providing lots of different Factory classes as parameters.

Comment: I mean you *could* have a separate constructor just for testing; `private Car(Func<CarType, EngineType > factory){...} public Car():this(EngineTypeFactory.GetEngineType){...}`

Comment: @r0bb077 Sorry for my stupid question, but aren't you just mapping `EnumA` to `EnumB` inside `EngineTypeFactory`? If so, why is it a "Factory"? Can't you use a `Dictionary<EnumA, EnumB>` for the same purpose?